# data binding in Kendo mobile

Tags: json, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I am doing a kendo mobile application and I'm trying to bind data from database for  listing using json call. I tried with the following code,but its not working Pls help me with this...thanks in advance...

my code is here:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "WebService/listing.php",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        datatype: "json"
                    }
                }
            });

            dataSource.bind("change", function () {
                $("#content").html(kendo.render(template, dataSource.view()));
            });

            dataSource.read();
            console.log(dataSource.view());

        });
```

Comment: Is your service visible to the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `change`function of the dataSource directly:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService/listing.php",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: "json"
        }
    },
    change: function() {
        $("#content").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
    }
});
```

Just some things to consider:

I'm assuming your JSON is correct

You're sure you use POST to get the data

your template is as well defined correctly

You're calling `dataSource.read()` AFTER the data is loaded (to make sure you're doing this, call `read()` within `$(document).ready(function(){dataSource.read();});` and define the dataSource itself first

I guess the last point is the most crucial ;)

That's all I am doing, so if it doesn't work that way there might be some mistake in the data format itself or in the template definition. Anything like console errors?

Cheers